# Github URL for sharing topic from user

Tags: github

How on Github can I link to repos from a particular handle having a particular topic?

Does the [topics](https://github.com/topics) feature support a URL route for this?

Like how do I show repos from [@ryanve](https://github.com/ryanve) with the topic [css](https://github.com/topics/css)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [search](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories) by a [particular topic](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-by-topic) and a [particular user](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories) by using the `topic` and `user` search qualifiers respectively. In your example, you can search for:

```
topic:css user:ryanve
```

This generates [the following URL](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Acss%20user%3Aryanve):

```
https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Acss+user%3Aryanve
```

Here, `%3A` is the [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for `:`.

In general, for topic `TOPIC` and user `USER`, you can use the URL:

```
https://github.com/search?q=topic%3ATOPIC+user%3AUSER
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!